# Full conditional posteriors

Tags: regression, bayesian, linear, prior, posterior

so up to now I dealt with posteriors in the form of:

$$p(\theta|x) \propto p(x|\theta) p(\theta)$$

No we started to model a linear regression with the bayesian approach:
$$Y \sim MVN(X\beta, \sigma^2I)$$
$$\beta|\sigma^2 \sim MVN(m, \sigma^2M)$$
$$\sigma^2 \sim IG(a_0, b_0)$$

We derived two posteriors (I guess) for the two full conditionals
$$p(\beta|\cdot) = p(\beta|\sigma^2, y) \propto p(y|\beta, \sigma^2)p(\beta|\sigma^2)$$
$$p(\sigma^2|\cdot) = p(\sigma^2|\beta, y) \propto p(y|\beta, \sigma^2)p(\beta|\sigma^2)p(\sigma^2)$$
The lecture slide notes that the $p(\sigma^2)$ is not included in the $p(\beta|\cdot)$ since it doesn't include $\beta$.

I don't understand the posteriors. Up to now I only knew the posterior form like $$posterior \propto likelihood \cdot prior$$. For me it looks like the posterior now needs all the priors, could that be? Like $$posterior \propto likelihood \cdot prior_1 \cdot ... \cdot prior_n$$

Maybe some one can provide some literature or give me a good explanation. Thanks in advance. :)

Note:

- there might be an inaccuracy because the lecture slides used $Y$ and $y$ maybe this is correct but I think it is not

Comment: You have to start from $\theta=(\beta,\sigma^2)$ as your parameter, where you can apply the "up to now" formula for the (joint) posterior, and then construct the conditional posteriors from that joint.

Comment: Then it follows: $P(\beta | \sigma^2, y) \propto P(y|\beta, \sigma^2) P(\beta, \sigma^2)$ ? What is $P(\beta, sigma^2)$ equal to?

Answer (score 4):

In the equation
$$\underbrace{p(\beta|\sigma^2, y)}_{\text{full conditional}} \propto p(y|\beta, \sigma^2)p(\beta|\sigma^2)$$
the left hand side $p(\beta|\sigma^2, y)$ is a density in $\beta$ for a given value of $(\sigma^2,y)$, which is proportional to the right hand side, with the proportionality understood as functions of $\beta$ only. The proportionality factor is what actually makes the left hand side $p(\beta|\sigma^2, y)$ a density, that is,
$$p(\beta|\sigma^2, y)=\dfrac{ p(y|\beta, \sigma^2)p(\beta|\sigma^2)}{\int
p(y|\beta, \sigma^2)p(\beta|\sigma^2)\,\text d\beta}$$
Thus it is completely equivalent to write
$$p(\beta|\sigma^2, y)\propto \underbrace{p(y|\beta, \sigma^2)p(\beta|\sigma^2)p(\sigma^2)}_{\text{joint density}} $$
since
$$p(\beta|\sigma^2, y)=\dfrac{ p(y|\beta, \sigma^2)p(\beta|\sigma^2)p(\sigma^2)}{\int
p(y|\beta, \sigma^2)p(\beta|\sigma^2)p(\sigma^2)\,\text d\beta}$$
shows that $p(\sigma^2)$ has no impact on the conditional density of $\beta$.

Comment: Thank you. So it is a mathematical reason why the $p(\sigma^2)$ is not included - it just cancels out. The lecture reasoned that is does not include $\beta$, maybe because they just used the proportional which did not include the denominator in the first place.

Comment: @BlankerHans: I am sorry, I do not understand your last sentence...